# Auto-Complete list for contact for wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I don't know how to get the auto complete list of contacts when the user types anything on the textbox. I am not getting any idea for this. I have researched a lot of place but could not achieve anything. i have also added an image for example. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download `AutoCompleteBox` from `Silverlight Toolkit`. Load all contacts into `AutoCompleteBox.ItemsSource`. Set `ValueMemberPath="propertyName"` to property that contains mobile phone (i.e. that you search for) or make your own filter criteria (`AutoCompleteBox.ItemFilter += ...`)

or

Create `ListBox` below `TextBox` and subscribe to `TextBox.TextChanged` event. Make `ListBox` items handling manually with filtering by `TextBox.Text`

Comment: Do you have any samples for the above?

Comment: No, it's just a ways to go to. If you don't know how to create `ListBox` or didn't work with `AutoCompleteBox`, start a new question. We can't write the whole application for you... Thanks for understanding.