# Auto-Complete list for contact for wp8

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I don't know how to get the auto complete list of contacts when the user types anything in the textbox. I am not getting any idea for this. I have researched a lot of places but could not achieve anything. I have also added an image for example. Can anyone help me with this?

[image: Picture of phone dial pad with autocomplete list]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend considering AutoSuggestBox control for WP8.X.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.autosuggestbox.aspx

There's a link for AutoComplete control for WP7:
[Auto-Complete list for contact for wp7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061786/auto-complete-list-for-contact-for-wp7?rq=1)

And there's how to access contact data from your code:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh286416(v=vs.105).aspx